# How to validate any 1 legend being selected, when deselect all the legends chart gets in loading state using ApexCharts.js

Tags: javascript

I have 3 legend/series in [an apex chart](https://prnt.sc/yPXqZuVI_Faw). I want to add validation one series being selected when 2 series are deselected.

I have tried with the legend click event implementation using the following code.

```
legendClick: (chartContext, seriesIndex, config)=>{
          if(config.config.series[seriesIndex]){
            if(config.config.series[seriesIndex].data.length){
              // series is being hidden
              if(seriesCounter>=1)
              seriesCounter--;
            } else {
              // series is being shown
              seriesCounter++;
            }
          }
          if(seriesCounter ===1){
            chart.updateOptions({
              legend:{
                onItemClick:{
                  toggleDataSeries:false
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
```

Using this code deselected legends are not being selected again.